# Who should care about lpe?

Tags: graphics, animations

Edd Barett, a TeXLive maintainer for OpenBSD has just committed [lpe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/) (an extensible drawing editor for LaTeX) to the ports tree. People who are familiar with my posts on this forum knows that when it comes to graphics and TeX I am PostScript bias (PSTricks and even pure PostScript more recently). However, I am curios to see if anybody is using lpe and how does it compare to other common approaches to create images for TeX (MetaPost, PSTricks, TikZ/PGF, Asymptote, Matlibplot, Sketch etc.)? It looks might be an interesting tool for Lua users (I am not one of those people).

Comment: Note that this isn't a forum, but a question and answer site. I'm not sure if your post actually fits here. It's technically not about a (La)TeX problem you have.

Comment: @Martin: you might want to change the plural form of "posts" into singular form? Also, AFAICS, there *is* a question posed, no?

Comment: @morbusg: Thanks, it should be indeed singular. I didn't said there is no question per se, but that is not really a solvable problem which a "correct" answer. This sounds more like a discussion or a listing of drawbacks/benefits and, as I wrote, I'm not sure if it really is a good fit here.